# Opening class in package from console in Java

Tags: java, class, console, cmd, package

So when i try to open a java class that's not in a package from the command prompt it all works fine, but when I try to open a class that's in a package it gives me NoClassDefFoundError. 
And when I list the package when I try to open the class (java somepackage/someclass) it says that it can't load or find the main class.

Any help?

Comment: not enough information. Frame your question with directory details ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can infer is, you have two classes:

Test.java:

```
// no package defined here

class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

so you can compile and run it using:

```
javac Test.java
java Test
```

Another class:

Test.java:

```
package test; // package defined here

class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

And thus doing same thing gives you error.
For this you need to be in the parent directory of 'test' folder in your terminal or cmd and use:

```
java test.Test
```

No problem with compiler. You can compile as usual using javac Test.java from inside 'test' folder.

Comment: Welcome :)! You should accept the answer if this is the case. It will help others..

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError means that your JVM can't find your class at runtime. This could be because it's not visible (set to private or protected, or just no access modifier).

It could also be missing from your build path

Comment: @splitgames is the package included in your build path?

Answer (score 0):

```
    package pkg1;
    public class Dataguise{
            public static void main(String [] args){
            System.out.println("My name is Maninder Singh");
            }
    }

    Suppose this is my code. My package name is pkg1.
    1. First you need to create pkg1 dirrectory if not existed.
    2. Run "javac Dataguise.java" command
    3. It will generate the "Dataguise.class" file and move this file to "pkg1" folder
    4. Now run "pkg1.Dataguise" command it will work.

    I was having the same issue so sharing my experience.
```

Answer (score 0):

What I assume is, you are creating a package and a class inside it, for example.

package com.vishwa.hello.commandLineArgs;

public class ComandLineArguments {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Command line arg is "+args[i]);
    }

}
```

}

When I try to compile and run the above code in command prompt (from the package folder) as
javac ComandLineArguments.java.
java ComandLineArguments 123 456.

You get the below error:
Error: Could not find or load main class ComandLineArguments
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/vishwa/hello/commandLineArgs/ComandLineArguments (wrong name: ComandLineArguments)

There are 2 ways to solve this:

1. Go to the root path of your project and then run.

   java com/vishwa/hello/commandLineArgs/ComandLineArguments 123 456
   789.
   Command line arg is 123.
   Command line arg is 456.
   Command line arg is 789.
2. If you want to run the program from the package directory, you need to specify the class path along with the complete package
   reference.
   java -cp
   /Users/16399/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.12.1.RELEASE/CoreJava/src/
   com/vishwa/ hello/commandLineArgs/ComandLineArguments 123 456 789.
   Command line arg is 123.  Command line arg is 456.  Command line arg is 789.